# Jackson JSON to JAVA conversion problems

Tags: java, json, jackson

So i am using Jackson to convert objects to JSON and then send them over a connection and convert them back to objects on the other side of the connection.  I ran into a problem when reading the JSON and attempting to turn it into a JAVA object it successfully changes JSON into multiple objects.  It is easier to see in an example:

```
ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
    Boolean test1 = null;
    String test2 = null;
    Integer test3 = null;
    Boolean obj = false;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        bytes = map.writeValueAsBytes(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
         test1 = map.readValue(bytes, Boolean.class);
         test2 = map.readValue(bytes, String.class);
         test3 = map.readValue(bytes, Integer.class);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
    }
    System.out.println("test1: " + test1 + "\ntest2: " + test2 + "\ntest3: " + test3);
```

And the output:

> FAILED 
>   test1: false 
>   test2: false 
>   test3: null

When attempting to convert the JSON Boolean to a String it was successful which is problematic for me because my current method looks similar to what is below and when the object deserialize  is of the wrong type it causes problems down the road.

```
public void JSONtoJAVA(Class<?> clazz)
{
    for(Event event : Events)
    {
        try
        {
            Object deserialized = map.readValue(bytes, event.getC());
            Event.getMethod().invoke(deserialized);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Failed ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: If anyone is having the same problem i figured out a solution i believe.  By using the @JsonTypeInfo annotation jackson which will tell jackson that this object requires more information such as class name.  This is not able to be used in the above example but on objects you create simply adding the line:
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
will solve your problem!